# Bug in sage in yupyter notebook, in defining matrix-valued function

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sage

I enter the following code

```
var('y')
f(y) = matrix([y])
f(0)
```

both in yupyter notebook, and then in sage cell, and it seems there is a bug with defining matrix function in yupyter notebook.

[code in yupyter notebook, does not work well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Sqh.png)

While the same code is entered in sage cell, everything works perfect.
How to resolve the issue in the yupyter notebook?

Thank you.

[code in sage cell, works properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PObBB.png)

Answer (score 2):

SageMathCell is running SageMath 9.5, the newest version. Your Jupyter notebook is running version 9.3. Version 9.5 introduces new functionality for SageMath symbolic expressions relating to matrices and vectors, see here for more:
https://wiki.sagemath.org/ReleaseTours/sage-9.5#Changes_to_symbolic_expressions

To solve your problem, you need to update your Jupyter notebooks kernel to SageMath 9.5